# Get variables with Gauß

Tags: matrices, gaussian-elimination

I try to find the solutions for the following expression with the Gauß Formula:

$$1x_1-1x_2+3x_3=0$$

$$2x_1 + 3x_2 - 1x_3 = 0$$

$$3x_1+7x_2-5x_3 =0$$

So i started:

$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 3 \\
        2 & 3 & -1 \\
        3 & 7 & -5 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$  Next i performed:  $I -2* II $  = $
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 3 \\
        0 & 5 & -7 \\
        0 & 10 & -14 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$

Now my problem started, when i count $-0.5*III + II$ the whole last row gets $0$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 3 \\
        0 & 5 & -7 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

Did i something wrong? How should i continue? Thanks

Comment: By the way, I think you mean you performed $II \rightarrow II - 2\times I$ (not $I - 2\times II$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the whole row hadn't become 0, then the only solution would be the trivia solution $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = 0$.

What you've done is correct. Now you can solve this by back-substitution. The system now is:
$x_1 - x_2 + 3x_3 = 0\\
5x_2 - 7x_3 = 0$

You can find expressions for $x_1$ and $x_2$ in terms of $x_3$, or assume a particular value for $x_3$ and solve for $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Should mean that $x_2=-7x_3$ and $x_1 = 4x_3$?

Comment: $x_2$ is correct. Check $x_1$ again (when you substitute $x_2 = -7x_3$ in the first equation, it becomes $+7x_3$).

Comment: Sorry I think my $x_2$ is incorrect it should be $x_2 = 7x_3$

Comment: Wait, the solution is wrong because I made a typo in my answer.

Comment: The second equation is $5x_2 - 7x_3 = 0$. So it should be $x_2 = 7x_3/5$, and $x_1 = -8x_3/5$. Sorry.
You can also write this more neatly as $x_1 = -8k, x_2 = 7k, x_3 = 5k$.